# How to convert from degrees to wind direction in Swift

Tags: swift

> The error message appears at every `=` sign

```
if let windDictionary = jsonObj!["wind"] as? NSDictionary {
    if let degrees = windDictionary["deg"] as? Float {
        if 348.75 <= degrees, degrees <= 360  { degrees =  "N" }
        else if 0 <= degrees,degrees <= 11.25 { degrees = "N" }
        else if 11.25 < degrees, degrees <= 33.75 { degrees = "NNE" }
        else if 33.75 < degrees, degrees <= 56.25 { degrees = "NE" }
        else if 56.25 < degrees, degrees <= 78.75 { degrees = "ENE" }
        else if 78.75 < degrees, degrees <= 101.25 { degrees = "E" }
        else if 101.25 < degrees, degrees <= 123.75 { degrees = "ESE" }
        else if 123.75 < degrees, degrees <= 146.25 { degrees = "SE" }
        else if 146.25 < degrees, degrees <= 168.75 { degrees = "SSE" }
        else if 168.75 < degrees, degrees <= 191.25 { degrees = "S" }
        else if 191.25 < degrees, degrees <= 213.75 { degrees = "SSW" }
        else if 213.75 < degrees, degrees <= 236.25 { degrees = "SW" }
        else if 236.25 < degrees, degrees <= 258.75 { degrees = "WSW" }
        else if 258.75 < degrees, degrees <= 281.25 { degrees = "W" }
        else if 281.25 < degrees, degrees <= 303.75 { degrees = "WNW" }
        else if 303.75 < degrees, degrees <= 326.25 { degrees = "NW" }
        else if 326.25 < degrees, degrees < 348.75 { degrees = "NNW" }
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot use the same variable for a number and a string ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already mentioned by @MartinR you can't assign a string to a float object. What you should do is enumerate your directions and create a custom initializer that takes an angle (Double). All you need is to add the offset 11.25 to it and then divide by 22.50. You can also truncate the reminder by 360 to make it work with angles beyond 360:

```
enum Direction: String, CaseIterable {
    case n, nne, ne, ene, e, ese, se, sse, s, ssw, sw, wsw, w, wnw, nw, nnw
}
```

---

```
extension Direction: CustomStringConvertible  {
    init<D: BinaryFloatingPoint>(_ direction: D) {
        self =  Self.allCases[Int((direction.angle+11.25).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 360)/22.5)]
    }
    var description: String { rawValue.uppercased() }
}
```

---

```
extension BinaryFloatingPoint {
    var angle: Self {
        (truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 360) + 360)
            .truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 360)
    }
    var direction: Direction { .init(self) }
}
```

---

usage:

```
let angle = 11.25
let direction = angle.direction
print(direction)  // "NNE\n"

let direction2 = Direction(348.75)
print(direction2)  // "N\n"

let direction3: Direction = .w
print(direction3)  // "W\n"
```

Comment: where do I use wind.direction.rawValue?

Comment: Everything converts and displays perfectly, thanks for all the help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign to a constant created through optional binding (a.k.a. `if-let statements`).

Instead, make and use a temporary variable, and then assign that to your object.

In addition, you are attempting to set a `String` value into a `float` variable.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have tried to define "degrees" as a variable, but I don't understand how to do that properly, in Leo's coding he makes it a Double, not a String. Are you saying do not use Float? Do I still keep my if let statements?